# Rotating 3D models in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, 3d

I'm looking to rotate a 3D model (.STL) that I loaded into excel using vba code. The end goal is to have a button that rotates in X axis by a specific amount of degrees, another in Y axis and another one in Z axis.

So far I've tried

```
Selection.ShapeRange.Model3D.RotationX = 303.7414166667
```

and

```
Model3D.ThreeD.RotationY = 10
```

that I got from other websites but neither of those seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a lot of background for this, but try to download the sample file from the link below and see if it helps you get going in the right direction.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/ued1rjexrd2by23/3d_Rotate.xls/file

[image]